# display the contents of map

Tags: visual-c++

How I can display the contents of this map that called index?

```
map< string, vector< pair<string, int> > > index
```

I make an iterator and made it in the beginning of the map using this code:

```
map< string, vector< pair<string, int> > >::iterator it;
it = index.begin();
```

...and I use this for loop to display the map contents but it gives me error:

```
for ( it =index.begin() ; it != index.end(); it++ )
    cout << (*it).first <<(*it).second <<endl;
```

I know that the error in `(*it).second` because it refers to vector, but I can't solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a `map<string, vector<pair<string, int> > index;`, I'd at least consider starting with a `multimap<string, pair<string, int> > index;`. Both accomplish essentially the same thing: some arbitrary number of `pair<string, int>` associated with one key (a string, in this case).

To display that, I'd start by overloading `operator<<` for the types in the container:

```
// the type of the data being stored:
typedef pair<string, int> data_t;

// an overload for that:
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, data_t> const &d) { 
    return os << d.first << d.second;
}
```

But the value_type of a map or multimap is a pair of the key and the associated data, so we need to provide an overload for that too:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, pair<string, data_t> const &d) {
    return os << d.first << d.second;
}
```

Then I'd use `std::copy` to copy the data to the stream:

```
copy(index.begin(), index.end(), ostream_iterator<data_t>(cout, "\n"));
```

So what'll happen is that each for each object in the map, it'll do essentially `cout << object[i]`. That will print out the key and the associated data. The associated data is itself a `pair<string, int>`, so that'll be printed out with the other overload of `operator <<`.

Answer (score 0):

`(*it).second` has no meaning by itself in this context. You need to use the vector public interface to extract data (see it in `vector` documentation) from it or do whatever manipulation that you need.